# What is the maximum number of bytes that can be specified in grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

**The problem:**

I am getting this error while receiving message in grpc:

```
grpc: received message larger than max (11509754 vs. 4194304)
```

**What I tried:**

I gave the option to increase the size of the message to be sent but it still gave the same error which means this setting of maximum size didn't work:

```
maxSizeOption := grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
if _, err := grpcClient.Foo(request, maxSizeOption); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

**Comments:**

I don't understand why the error message shows 4194304(=4MB).
Is there a maximum number of bytes that can be set for grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize?

To add, when I passed 10MB to MaxCallSendMsgSize, I got the error:

```
trying to send message larger than max (11509754 vs. 10485760)
```

This was expected.

**Addendum:**

When I passed 10MB to MaxCallSendMsgSize and MaxCallRecvMsgSize, I got the same error:

```
size := 50* 1024 * 1024
maxSendSizeOption := grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(size)
maxRecvSizeOption := grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(size)
if _, err := grpcClient.Foo(request,maxSendSizeOption,maxRecvSizeOption); err != nil {
   return err
}
```

error:

```
grpc: received message larger than max (11509754 vs. 4194304)
```

Comment: The first error is from receiving, but you are setting the max send size.

Comment: I updated my post. When I passed 10MB to MaxCallSendMsgSize and MaxCallRecvMsgSize, I got the same error.

Comment: You must setup those options on both sides, client & server.

Comment: Thanks JimB and Зелёный!
I set those options server too, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I set those options server too, and it worked.
Thanks JimB and Зелёный!

```
// server side
size := 1024 * 1024 * 50
server := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(size),
    grpc.MaxRecvMsgSize(size),
)
```